# Error in textConnection(): all connections are in use

Tags: r

I have read most of the posts concerning an error of this type but neither applies to my case. I am new in R, working on an assignment for school based on Nolan and Lang's book Data Science Case Studies in R. I am working on using stats to identify spam, url for the code can be found [here](http://rdatasciencecases.org/Spam/code.R), which require working with files from http://spamassassin.apache.org/old/publiccorpus/ (which are pretty big)

Now the problem I am facing is the following (just posting the chunks of code where I have encountered the issue):

```
sampleSplit = lapply(sampleEmail, splitMessage)

processHeader = function(header)
{
       # modify the first line to create a key:value pair
  header[1] = sub("^From", "Top-From:", header[1])

  headerMat = read.dcf(textConnection(header), all = TRUE)
  headerVec = unlist(headerMat)

  dupKeys = sapply(headerMat, function(x) length(unlist(x)))
  names(headerVec) = rep(colnames(headerMat), dupKeys)

  return(headerVec)
}

headerList = lapply(sampleSplit, 
                    function(msg) {
                      processHeader(msg$header)} )

contentTypes = sapply(headerList, function(header) 
                                        header["Content-Type"])
names(contentTypes) = NULL
contentTypes

hasAttach = grep("^ *multi", tolower(contentTypes))
hasAttach

boundaries = getBoundary(contentTypes[ hasAttach ])
boundaries

boundary = boundaries[9]
body = sampleSplit[[15]]$body

bString = paste("--", boundary, sep = "")
bStringLocs = which(bString == body)
bStringLocs

eString = paste("--", boundary, "--", sep = "")
eStringLoc = which(eString == body)
eStringLoc

diff(c(bStringLocs[-1], eStringLoc))

### This code has mistakes in it - and we fix them later!
processAttach = function(body, contentType){

  boundary = getBoundary(contentType)

  bString = paste("--", boundary, "$", sep = "")
  bStringLocs = grep(bString, body)

  eString = paste("--", boundary, "--$", sep = "")
  eStringLoc = grep(eString, body)

  n = length(body)

  if (length(eStringLoc) == 0) eStringLoc = n + 1
  if (length(bStringLocs) == 1) attachLocs = NULL
  else attachLocs = c(bStringLocs[-1],  eStringLoc)

  msg = body[ (bStringLocs[1] + 1) : min(n, (bStringLocs[2] - 1), 
                                         na.rm = TRUE)]

  if ( eStringLoc < n )
    msg = c(msg, body[ (eStringLoc + 1) : n ])

  if ( !is.null(attachLocs) ) {
    attachLens = diff(attachLocs, lag = 1) 
    attachTypes = mapply(function(begL, endL) {
      contentTypeLoc = grep("[Cc]ontent-[Tt]ype", body[ (begL + 1) : (endL - 1)])
      contentType = body[ begL + contentTypeLoc]
      contentType = gsub('"', "", contentType )
      MIMEType = sub(" *Content-Type: *([^;]*);?.*", "\\1", contentType)
      return(MIMEType)
    }, attachLocs[-length(attachLocs)], attachLocs[-1])
  }

  if (is.null(attachLocs)) return(list(body = msg, attachInfo = NULL) )
  else return(list(body = msg, 
                   attachDF = data.frame(aLen = attachLens, 
                                         aType = attachTypes,
                                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))                                
}

bodyList = lapply(sampleSplit, function(msg) msg$body)
attList = mapply(processAttach, bodyList[hasAttach], 
                 contentTypes[hasAttach], 
                 SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

lens = sapply(attList, function(processedA) 
                           processedA$attachDF$aLen)
head(lens)

attList[[2]]$attachDF

body = bodyList[hasAttach][[2]]
length(body)

body[35:45]

processAttach = function(body, contentType){

  n = length(body)
  boundary = getBoundary(contentType)

  bString = paste("--", boundary, sep = "")
  bStringLocs = which(bString == body)
  eString = paste("--", boundary, "--", sep = "")
  eStringLoc = which(eString == body)

  if (length(eStringLoc) == 0) eStringLoc = n
  if (length(bStringLocs) <= 1) {
    attachLocs = NULL
    msgLastLine = n
    if (length(bStringLocs) == 0) bStringLocs = 0
  } else {
    attachLocs = c(bStringLocs[ -1 ],  eStringLoc)
    msgLastLine = bStringLocs[2] - 1
  }

  msg = body[ (bStringLocs[1] + 1) : msgLastLine] 
  if ( eStringLoc < n )
    msg = c(msg, body[ (eStringLoc + 1) : n ])

  if ( !is.null(attachLocs) ) {
    attachLens = diff(attachLocs, lag = 1) 
    attachTypes = mapply(function(begL, endL) {
      CTloc = grep("^[Cc]ontent-[Tt]ype", body[ (begL + 1) : (endL - 1)])
      if ( length(CTloc) == 0 ) {
        MIMEType = NA
      } else {
        CTval = body[ begL + CTloc[1] ]
        CTval = gsub('"', "", CTval )
        MIMEType = sub(" *[Cc]ontent-[Tt]ype: *([^;]*);?.*", "\\1", CTval)   
      }
      return(MIMEType)
    }, attachLocs[-length(attachLocs)], attachLocs[-1])
  }

  if (is.null(attachLocs)) return(list(body = msg, attachDF = NULL) )
  return(list(body = msg, 
             attachDF = data.frame(aLen = attachLens, 
                                     aType = unlist(attachTypes),
                                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))                                
}                       

readEmail = function(dirName) {
       # retrieve the names of files in directory
  fileNames = list.files(dirName, full.names = TRUE)
       # drop files that are not email
  notEmail = grep("cmds$", fileNames)
  if ( length(notEmail) > 0) fileNames = fileNames[ - notEmail ]

       # read all files in the directory
  lapply(fileNames, readLines, encoding = "latin1")
}

processAllEmail = function(dirName, isSpam = FALSE)
{
       # read all files in the directory
  messages = readEmail(dirName)
  fileNames = names(messages)
  n = length(messages)

       # split header from body
  eSplit = lapply(messages, splitMessage)
  rm(messages)

       # process header as named character vector
  headerList = lapply(eSplit, function(msg) 
                                 processHeader(msg$header))

       # extract content-type key
  contentTypes = sapply(headerList, function(header) 
                                       header["Content-Type"])

       # extract the body
  bodyList = lapply(eSplit, function(msg) msg$body)
  rm(eSplit)

       # which email have attachments
  hasAttach = grep("^ *multi", tolower(contentTypes))

       # get summary stats for attachments and the shorter body
  attList = mapply(processAttach, bodyList[hasAttach], 
                   contentTypes[hasAttach], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

  bodyList[hasAttach] = lapply(attList, function(attEl) 
                                           attEl$body)

  attachInfo = vector("list", length = n )
  attachInfo[ hasAttach ] = lapply(attList, 
                                  function(attEl) attEl$attachDF)

       # prepare return structure
  emailList = mapply(function(header, body, attach, isSpam) {
                       list(isSpam = isSpam, header = header, 
                            body = body, attach = attach)
                     },
                     headerList, bodyList, attachInfo, 
                     rep(isSpam, n), SIMPLIFY = FALSE )
  names(emailList) = fileNames

  invisible(emailList)
}
```

Everything runs fine right up to:

```
emailStruct = mapply(processAllEmail, fullDirNames,
                     isSpam = rep( c(FALSE, TRUE), 3:2))      
emailStruct = unlist(emailStruct, recursive = FALSE)

sampleStruct = emailStruct[ indx ]

save(emailStruct, file="emailXX.rda")
```

I get the error Error in textConnection(header) : all connections are in use, therefore it doesn't recognize "emailStruct", which I need later on. I seriously don't know how to overcome it so that I can continue with the rest of the code, which requires some of these variables to work.

Comment: So is the error with that *last* line of that last code block? The `save` function call?

Comment: No, the error shows with the line of code: 
emailStruct = mapply(processAllEmail, fullDirNames,
                     isSpam = rep( c(FALSE, TRUE), 3:2))

Comment: `closeAllConnections()` will close them all.

Comment: I have already tried closeAllConnections()} but doesn't do anything! I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Please delete the lines after the one that fails - its misleading otherwise.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks! Your suggestion worked flawlessly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you run `textConnection()` you are opening a text connection, but you are never closing it. Try closing it explicitly after you read from it

```
read.dcf(tc<-textConnection(header), all = TRUE)
close(tc)
```